# Unwanted breakline behavior - general explanation

Tags: html, css, text

I have experienced cross-browser problem that a line on a page in a narrow column is breaked too early despite the space left where the last word could easily fit.
Firstly I thought there is something wrong with my stylesheet but it looks the same in a simple fiddle which I created (no php tags, no line-breakers, etc.):
I am sorry as it's in Czech Language but for demo purpose I hope it's ok.
It shows the same bug in FF,IE and Chrome on Win7 and Win8, even on iPad.

---

**Link to fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Grows/q9wqeu14/1/

**Demo:**

*HTML:*

```
<div class="column">
    <p>Jsme tým zkušených profesionálů, který Vám pomůže s kompletním IT řešením. Spravujeme     IT techniku jak menším firmám do deseti uživatelů, tak i velkým společnostem se stovkami stanic a desítkami serveů. Náklady na externí správu sítě jsou zcela individuální a závisí na rozsahu sítě (počet serverů, stanic, aktivních prvků apod.), dohodnuté frekvenci návštěv a garantované době servisních zásahů. U menších firem se tato částka obvykle pohybuje v jednotkách tisíců korun měsíčně, takže se určitě vyplatí více, než zaměstnávat vlastního správce sítě.</p>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <ul>
        <li>Individuální přístup a vstřícnou péči o uživatele výpočetní techniky</li>
        <li>Pravidelnou údržbu výpočetní techniky - minimalizují se její výpadky</li>
        <li>Garanci servisního zásahu - minimalizuje ztráty způsobené výpadkem</li>
        <li>Řízení IT procesů - provozujeme systém HELPDESK pro hlášení servisních požadavků, telefonickou linku HOT-LINE a automatický monitorovací systém NAGIOS, který nepřetržitě monitoruje chod Vašich klíčových zařízení</li>
        <li>Poradenství a konzultační služby</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <ul>
        <li>Finanční úspora - IT specialistu využíváte jen tehdy, je-li to potřeba. Ušetříte na mzdových nákladech, odborných školeních apod.</li>
        <li>Flexibilita - služba je smluvně garantovaná, nemusíte řešit nemoci, dovolené, zástupy apod.</li>
        <li>Profesionalita - pracujeme v týmu, máme zkušenosti, kvalitní technické zázemí a podporu našich dodavatelů. Jsme schopni minimalizovat rizika výpadku sítě či je zkrátit na minimum.</li>
        <li>Přenesení zodpovědnosti za bezproblémový chod Vaší sítě na dodavatele</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
body {
    font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial'; text-align: left;    
}

.column {
    width: 214px; border: 1px black solid; 
}

li {
    list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: outside;
}
```

---

What me and both my client see is the weird break between 3rd and 4th row but also in more text.
I tried to search similar questions here and Google it but no success.

Is this a standard browser behavior or there is something wrong?
I really don't want to use manual line-breakers like br, wbr, nbsp, etc.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers, Martin

---- UPDATED ----

Thanks for the given solutions guys so far.
There are no white-spaces of any kind it's just pure text, so I can't remove any.
Also it must stay in three divs.

I guess it's some weird behavior of czech language in browser but I didn't see something like this before.

Maybe I can't do anything with it and this could be an answer too :)

---- SOLVED ---

Emmanuel was right.
There was something weird with some space characters. When I deleted them and typed space again, it dissapeared. Thank you so much! If someone explain this to me I would be very happy because in the source-code there weren't any visible "white-space" like tags...

Comment: There is something wrong with the space character you have used at: `řešením. Spravujeme`.

Comment: These are not tags. They are Unicode non-breaking-space characters. They can slip in when, for example, you accidentally type Cmd-space instead of space. They don't look any different from normal spaces in your editor. If you read the entire thread linked to from my answer, I think you should get the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Remove non breaking space from <h4>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120368/remove-non-breaking-space-from-h4/26120556#26120556). In your editor, search for non-breaking spaces if you know how to do that, turn on a mode which displays them, or do a search-and-replace of non-breaking spaces with regular old sp0aces.

Comment: Thanks for advise, but it's pure text, no non-breaking tags at all.

Comment: What I'm saying is, there are things in your text that **look** like spaces, but actually they are non-breaking space Unicode characters. I verified this by changing them in your fiddle.

Comment: torazaburo, you are right. Thank you. Text was copied from Word to the editor so there probably occured the incorrect input.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove second and third div like this:**

```
<div class="column">
    <p>Jsme tým zkušených profesionálů, který Vám pomůže s kompletním IT řešením. Spravujeme     IT techniku jak menším firmám do deseti uživatelů, tak i velkým společnostem se stovkami stanic a desítkami serveů. Náklady na externí správu sítě jsou zcela individuální a závisí na rozsahu sítě (počet serverů, stanic, aktivních prvků apod.), dohodnuté frekvenci návštěv a garantované době servisních zásahů. U menších firem se tato částka obvykle pohybuje v jednotkách tisíců korun měsíčně, takže se určitě vyplatí více, než zaměstnávat vlastního správce sítě.</p>

    <ul>
        <li>Individuální přístup a vstřícnou péči o uživatele výpočetní techniky</li>
        <li>Pravidelnou údržbu výpočetní techniky - minimalizují se její výpadky</li>
        <li>Garanci servisního zásahu - minimalizuje ztráty způsobené výpadkem</li>
        <li>Řízení IT procesů - provozujeme systém HELPDESK pro hlášení servisních požadavků, telefonickou linku HOT-LINE a automatický monitorovací systém NAGIOS, který nepřetržitě monitoruje chod Vašich klíčových zařízení</li>
        <li>Poradenství a konzultační služby</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li>Finanční úspora - IT specialistu využíváte jen tehdy, je-li to potřeba. Ušetříte na mzdových nákladech, odborných školeních apod.</li>
        <li>Flexibilita - služba je smluvně garantovaná, nemusíte řešit nemoci, dovolené, zástupy apod.</li>
        <li>Profesionalita - pracujeme v týmu, máme zkušenosti, kvalitní technické zázemí a podporu našich dodavatelů. Jsme schopni minimalizovat rizika výpadku sítě či je zkrátit na minimum.</li>
        <li>Přenesení zodpovědnosti za bezproblémový chod Vaší sítě na dodavatele</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And this fixes the problem...how??

Comment: Removing the divs in the OP's original fiddle does **not** solve the problem. I suspect in cutting and pasting into jsbin, you may have replaced the problematic non-breaking spaces with regular spaces. In any case, why would the presence or absence of surrounding divs affect anything?

Comment: Thanks for replies, divs have to stay, final code should look similar to this, I didn't want to make demo unnecessary complex.http://jsfiddle.net/Grows/q9wqeu14/9/

Answer (score 0):

You just need `word-break: break-all;` style to column. [WORKING CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/q9wqeu14/8/)

Comment: That's a great solution if you want to not break words at spaces at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you look specifically at:

> řešením. Spravujeme

in a HEX editor, the "space" between the '.' and 'S' is actually 2 bytes:

```
C2 A0
```

`C2A0` is a [non-breaking space in UTF-8 HEX](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm) and a "normal" breaking space is HEX `20`.

Since this is a non-breaking space, the browser doesn't consider it a valid point to break the word to line-wrap.